# Error enabling cloud integration in existing application - GAE

Tags: google-app-engine

I am trying to add APIs to my existing application but the option does not appear.

I have tried creating a `'Google Cloud Project' in APPLICATION SETTING > CLOUD INTEGRATION` but this returns an error after I refresh the page:

```
"An error ocurred when creating the project." Please retry." (Google typo for "occurred")
```

I don't really want to create a new application as a workaround but it looks as though this may be the only option at the moment.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please star this issue: http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=9602

Comment: The issue was fixed in Aug 2013 -- so can this question stop being seen as "unanswered"?  E.g @smac3 can you post a self-answer and accept it?  Pretty please...?-)

Comment: @smac have you been able to do this? could you please close this question?

Answer (score 0):

As indicated by @Gilberto and @Alex, this was a [known issue](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=9602) and has since been fixed as of [August, 2013](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/wiki/SdkReleaseNotes#Version_1.8.3_-_August_6,_2013) under **`PHP`**.